# How to customize Shiny Dashboard tab colors?

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm working on customizing my Shiny Dashboard appearance. In the code below, I show that I've managed to customize the logo, navbar, and *full* tab hover appearance, but I haven't been able to customize the *side* of my tab hover appearance. By default, the very left of a tab on Shiny Dashboard turns the theme color when clicked/hovered on, but I'm trying to change it to a custom color. How do I do this?

(I've included an image of what I mean, the color to the left of the tab is the default blue but I want to change it)
[CLICK FOR IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDzN6.png)

```
    #customize header + navbar to be exactly the color I want
    tags$head(tags$style(HTML('
        .skin-blue .main-header .logo {
                              background-color: #0c6cc4;
                              }
        .skin-blue .main-header .logo:hover {
                              background-color: #0c6cc4;
                              }
        .skin-blue .main-header .navbar {
                              background-color: #0c6cc4;
                              }
        .skin-blue .main-sidebar .sidebar .sidebar-menu a:hover{
                              background-color: #0c6cc4;
                              }
                              '))),
```

Answer (score 0):

Include the following CSS (it's the `border-left-color`):

```
.skin-blue .sidebar-menu > li.active > a {
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #1e282c;
  border-left-color: #0c6cc4;
}
```